Ubuntu 24.04 dual boot win11 initramfs error
So, I recently got a Lenovo Ideapad Slim 3 that came with Windows 11. I decided to make it dual boot with Ubuntu 24.04. Install seemed to work ok, but when the grub window appears and I select Ubuntu, I get this:
BusyBox v1.36.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.36.1-6ubuntu3.1) built-in shell (ash)
(initramfs)

I type 'exit' and get this:
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
--Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules: ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=e5d4b1c7-b00a-41bc-8903-e9693c289d1c does not exist

I gather somehow the system cannot find a crucial partition, but I cannot find how to fix it. Upon searching some people seem to have similar problems, but no solutions have worked as yet.
Things tried:

Reinstalling Ubuntu
Turned off secure boot in UEFI. Returned the possibility to run memtest from grub boot.
David's suggestion from UUID=xxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell on standard (no dual boot) on Lenovo Idea Pad 3
Listing the partitions at grub command line shows everything fine as far as I can see.
Running boot-repair twice. "Successful" both times. Last report here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2FJt3HV56f

I would drop the dual boot and just run Ubuntu, but I have a suspicion I'd face the same issue. If you need more info just ask and I'll provide.

Please repost your boot-repair link, the one in your original posting does not exist.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please do not add SOLVED to the question title and the answer inside the question. Use the Answer Your Own Question button below to answer your question. Then after the waiting period click on the gray check mark ✔️ next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark your question as solved and help others.


I tried a lot of other things that didn't work, but here is what did
as formulated by chatgpt linux server expert who helped me narrow down
the problem and adress it:

Rebuild the Initramfs with UFS Modules The most likely cause of the (initramfs) drop is that the ufshcd_pci module is missing or not being
loaded early enough during the boot process. Step 1: Ensure ufshcd_pci
is Included in Initramfs

Boot into the live USB and mount your root partition:



       sudo mount /dev/sdb5 /mnt
       sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
       sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
       sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
       sudo chroot /mnt ```

 2. Open the initramfs-tools module configuration file:



   nano /etc/initramfs-tools/modules ```


Add the following lines to ensure the UFS modules are included:

       ufshcd_core
       ufshcd_pci ```

       This forces the initramfs to include these modules during boot.

 4. Rebuild the initramfs:


   update-initramfs -u -k all ```


Exit the chroot:

       exit
       sudo umount /mnt/dev
       sudo umount /mnt/proc
       sudo umount /mnt/sys
       sudo umount /mnt" ```

Hope that helps the next person.


Answer moved from OP's quesiton.
